# how to check if ElasticSearch's Restore is finished?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, request

Can I monitor Elasticsearch's Restore process? I am
looking for a GET request in Elasticsearch's API that checks if restore has finished.

I'm restoring indices from a snapshot I've created, but how can I know if the restore has finished?

waitUntilRestoreFromSnapshotIsFinished(ElasticsearchClient EsClient) {

//what to do here??

}

Comment: The main cluster state should change to green or yellow (depending on what you're waiting for), or you could possibly check the [Indices Recovery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-recovery.html) endpoint for more detailed information about the recovery progress. Not sure how you'd do it with the client you're using.

Comment: use can use this command curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_status?pretty"

Comment: @Yotam, I am having the similar issue to wait until a snapshot is restored completely into elasticsearch. IT would be great if you could share the findings.

Comment: @Ann posted an answer that helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an answer for this that helped me, hope it helps you all:

You can use this Elasticsearch API:
GET: <your_host>/_cat/recovery?v&pretty&human

Then filter the result by the recovery_type of "snapshot" and look at the progress percentage
(for one snapshot there might be more than one recovery)